# Execute javascript within a fusion tables popup window?

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

Good afternoon.

Does anyone know of a super-simple way to execute javascript from within a fusion tables map popup window, based solely on the contents of the table? In such a situation, I could, for example, trigger an alert() call showing test text, all without leaving the Fusion Tables environment at google.com.

I know I can probably futz with API documentation and firebug until I figure something out for my app, but I figured it was worth asking for the simplest solution before moving on to more complex stuff.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Sorry, you can't, script-code will be removed from infoWindows created via the FusionTable-UI

Comment: That's what I had feared. Thanks for the answer.